# Script to get the relative path in a for loop which recursively scans a directory

Tags: bash, relative-path

Suppose we use a `for` loop to scan a directory (*folder0*):

```
for element in $(ls) ...
```

This directory may contain files and subfolders which may contain files and subfolders and so on.

Suppose we are interested in the path relatively to *folder0* when we get a *folder* element in the `for` loop. For example, if we have the absolute path

*irrelevant_part/folder0/remaining_part/folderN*

the relevant part will be

*folder0/remaining_part/folderN*.

How can we do to obtain this result in order to assign it to a variable to be utilized in the rest of the script?

**Edit**

I ask to not consider this question as a  duplicate of the one I had indicated, because it doesn't fit my problem.

Instead a possible solution is this:

```
cd irrelevant_part/folder0
for element in $(ls -R)
do
    if [[ $element == *"."* ]]; then
        f0=folder0
        abbr_path=$element
        # Substituting . with folder0 in the abbreviated path
        abbr_path="${abbr_path/./$f0}"
        nul=""
       # Substituting : with null in the abbreviated path
        requested_path="${abbr_path/:/$nul}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I suggest to replace `$(ls)` with `*`.

Comment: @Cyrus is the equivalent of `$(ls -R) ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing uniques names:

```
my_var="$(find .  -type d -name folderN 2>/dev/null|awk -F\folder0\/ '/folder0\//{print FS$2}')"
```

Comment: But this way how can I use the `awk` output in the rest of the script (perhaps with *process substitution*)?

Comment: Is it not necessary to specify before the action the field separator: `BEGIN { FS="/" }` ?

Comment: The `FS` is parsed here: `-F\folder0\/` so `FS` is equal to `folder0/` and printed by th eaction

Comment: If I use `$(ls)` or *, I'll get only the first level of subdirectories, and if I use `$(ls -R)` I'll get superfluous elements in the `for` loop (e.g. also the single name of the folder). Anyway your suggestion doesn't work. I put `$element` for `folderN` in the syntax you proposed.

Comment: I've marked your answer because it is a correct solution to the problem of obtaining a sub-path from an absolute one. However it doesn't work in my contest because the `for` loop gets abbreviated path elements of the kind *./.../folderN* where the `. ` stands for the *folder0*. This is why it never find that folder. Incidentally the solution to my problem is very simple now: I must consider in the recursive loop a little test i.e. if `element ` contains a dot; in this case I have immediately the relative path I need.

Comment: But note that the answer I've marked it is *not* the correct one to my question.